# ReCAPTCHA always incorrect

Tags: php, curl, recaptcha

I have a page with a recaptcha in it, and it had been running without any problem for two months. But now, since a few days, it has been acting weird. I have tried many several times, but the captcha is simply not working, the verification part.

Here is the code

```
$captcharesponse = test_input($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]);
$status = captcha($captcharesponse);
...
function captcha($t){
    $captcharesponse = $t;
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'secret=7...PRIVATE_KEY...S&response=' . $captcharesponse);

    $result = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);
    curl_close($curl);

    if($result['success'] == false){
        error_log(date("Y-M-d, D h:i:s A") . " : Result = " . $result['success'] . ", and error = " . $result['error-codes']);
    }
    return $result['success'];      
}
```

And no matter what, even if I am not even entering the captcha, still the page is taking too long, and hence nothing is working. Please not that other things are simply skipped if the captcha is wrong, so there is no way that other things are causing the delay.

Thanks in advance

PS. I am not using any kind or library or anything, and it did use to work some time back without any problem.

The 'test_input()' code:

```
function test_input($data){
       $data = trim($data);
       $data = stripslashes($data);
       $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
       return $data;
}
```

Comment: What changed? Something had to change.

Comment: Is your captcha returning incorrect or is it delaying? What's your problem actually?

Comment: What is being returned by your `test_input(...)`?

Comment: @user2768665 It is delyed(probaly, or at least making the page really slow) and also it is always returning incorrect

Comment: @DimasPante `test_input()` check if there are any undesired characters, like quotes or parantheses, etc, and removes them

Comment: Oh I see, but it's not returning empty, right?

Comment: @DimasPante no, it returns the same sting, remove all the braces and stuff

Comment: @DimasPante I have updated the code in the original question, hope that helps

Comment: Strange. If you put only a `curl_exec($curl); die(curl_error($curl));`, it brings something?

Comment: @DimasPante I haven't tried, honestly speaking I know nothing, nothing about curl, and even when it comes to PHP, i know only basics. I ripped off this code from some tutorial. Also, I recently learned during my research that there are many others too that are having trouble setting up the new reCAPTCHA properly, though some have managed to to so.

Comment: Well, if that's the case, try my answer now, using Google's Recaptchalib

Comment: Thanks for all the effort you put in, but the problem has been fixed, automatically, as I mentioned in the other comment. Though, I might use your answer if I ever run into some problem again. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been resolved,
Apparently it was a problem on reCAPTCHA's end. The above provided code is now working flawlessly, and all slow-performance problems have been resolved as well.

Thank you all.

PS. Others can use this code if the want.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say to use the recaptcha library, available at:

https://github.com/google/recaptcha

First of all, download the files, most important is recaptchalib.php (you can download all files clicking the `download zip` button at right).

Then unzip it to your folder and use it like the example unzipped along (example-recaptcha.php):

```
<?php
require_once "recaptchalib.php";

// Register API keys at https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin
$siteKey = "YOURSITEKEY";
$secret = "YOURSECRET";
$lang = "en";
$resp = null; // The response from reCAPTCHA
$error = null; // The error code from reCAPTCHA, if any
$reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);

if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) { // Was there a reCAPTCHA response?
    $resp = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
        $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
    );
}
?>
<html>
  <head><title>reCAPTCHA Example</title></head>
  <body>
<?php
if ($resp != null && $resp->success) {
    echo "You got it!";
}
?>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo $siteKey;?>"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript"
          src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=<?php echo $lang;?>">
      </script>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="test recaptcha" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But isn't this library only for reCAPTCHA 1.0, while I'm using version 2.0, also, more importantly, I want to know that what is wrong with my code, that I am not able to use, so that I won't make similar mistakes again, Thanks anyway

Comment: Oh, don't worry, the captcha started working again today, suddenly, without making any changes to it, probably it was something with the google server

Comment: Hah, crazy! I always joke that IT isn't an exact science after all :P